# How do I get consistent sound during Bansuri practice

Tags: beginner, exercises, indian-classical, breathing, bansuri

I am teaching myself Bansuri (23", A scale), using YouTUBE videos.

Just recently I understood the concept of octaves, i.e. blowing sound hard and soft with same closed holes will produce high and low octave, respectively.

I am also practicing SA RE GA MA PA DHA NI SA

For past day or so, I noticed that I have to exert to make same low octave sound. Yesterday I didn't practice, thinking I need to give diaphragm/lungs a rest.

Today when I tried there were times I couldn't make low octave sound. I had to take deep breath from diaphragm and try again.

I am getting anxiety over this .... I really wish to learn Bansuri for hobby.

Question is, how to get consistent sound on Bansuri. Is it possible that I should limit practice to 30 minutes, daily, and take minute break in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you are closing the holes properly with fingers while trying out lower octave notes. Also Practicing on empty stomach may help producing lower octave notes.
Try to produce long notes initially. My teacher used to make us practice one note per breath ( as long as a minute ) in initial days. Don't worry, keep practicing it will come.
Playing long notes also helps bowing steady without any vibrations. Hope this helps

Comment: Those vibrations are unsettling .... glad these will go away with practice. Interestingly enough, I am always hungry after 30 minute of Bansuri practice!

Comment: How's your practice going on?

Comment: still getting vibration on higher notes. Trying to hold each note for a minute ...